# WebView in ListView drawn twice (Why and how to solve?)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I am using a ListView with a WebView every 30 items for special HTML ads (animated) which are provided from a WebServer. This normally works okay. But sometimes it seems to draw the content of the WebView twice as seen in the screenshot below. The WebView continues animating but the misplaced (left bottom) drawing stays the same. When one interacts with the screen (scrolls) the wrongly drawn space disappears.

[image: Screenshot showing the problem]

Now my questions are:

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I prevent this from happening?

My current guess for Nr. 1 is: Somehow the WebView gets positioned in the left bottom just for a quick time where it as well draws. Then it gets positioned correctly but the ListView does not redraw that area because it thinks all is still at the same position.

Thanks to anyone who can help.

**UPDATE:**

I used the same WebView with the animation centered in a RelativeLayout. The same problem occurred there. So the problem is not in the ListView.

Comment: What is your android device version? Also, you can give it a try to this library : https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview

Comment: Show your code. And try to refresh your ListView by calling `listView.invalidateViews()` or `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: I have not tested it on all versions. But it happens on 4.2 and 4.4. Sadly I can not switch the ChromeView because the WebView is made through a library. Because it is a library, I as well can not share the source code in there.

Comment: @Manu notifyDataSetChanged() is called at the right time. Just calling it again would not help. And invalidateViews would probably work, but it would need to be at the right time. Question is: When is the right time. Calling it every second or so is not okay.

Comment: @PatrickBoos what can you share? Perhaps at least the `ListView` code, where you use the `WebViews`.

Comment: @user3249477 Just wrote an update now. I tried to use the same WebView outside of the ListView and it produces the same problem. So the issue is not in the ListView.

Comment: @PatrickBoos You should have started your question with this statement: *The problem is in the code which I cannot show you*.

Comment: @user3249477 I am working on some sample code that reproduces the problem. Some code I can share. But I think it is a general problem. With animations and the WebView. So I was thinking that maybe someone else experienced this already.

Comment: Please post your layout xml file and your listview adapter class here

Comment: Run Hierarchy Viewer http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html to see what is going on. I would start with this tool instead guessing.

Comment: a possible related issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20051

Comment: @Loop already did. But it does not show any other view. That second drawing does not show up in hierarchyviewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in the WebView coming from the advertiser. The problem seems to be setting the LayerType to HARDWARE. That caused the Problem. Setting the the LayerType to NONE or SOFTWARE the problem went away. Now I just wonder WHY that caused the problem.

A normal WebView uses LAYER_TYPE_NONE by default.

Solution in short:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WebViews don't go well with ListViews, you may have to do a lot of hacks, including handling touch events, etc.

If you list doesn't display an 'infinite' list of items, or at least the list is never too big, you can maybe give a try on this custom listview from this other post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21878703/684582

it was designed to support a ListView inside a ScrollView, but it might just help you on your problem without much redesign. I hope it helps! Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I just tried it outside a ListView and it has the same problem. So the problem is not ListView related. But thank you anyway!